# TextInputEditText appearance does not change when disable

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.android

Why TextInputEditText appearance does not change when I disable it? How can I change the appearance of it?

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE3IV.png)

```html
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:enabled="false"
      style="@style/Layout.Field.TextField"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
          android:id="@+id/testing"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:hint="Outlined box" />
  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried this view and found that it has changed when disable but the TextInputLayout cover the change part. So if you delete the TextInputLayout, you will find the little difference between the enable and disable.

In addition, you can use a selector to make the difference more clearly.

selector.xml in the drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@color/one"/>
<item android:state_enabled="false"
      android:drawable="@color/two"/>
</selector>
```

color.xml in the values folder:

```
<color name="one">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</color>
<color name="two">@android:color/darker_gray</color>
```

use the selector.xml

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
      android:id="@+id/testing"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:enabled="false"
      android:hint="Outlined box" 
      android:background="@drawable/selector"/>
```